# $f$ is a continuous injective mapping. Is $f$ an open mapping?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis

Let $O \subset R^n$ and $f : O \to R^n$ be an injective and continuous mapping. Prove that $f$ is open, i.e, for each open subset $A \subseteq O$,   $f(O)$ is open subset of $R^n$.

P.S. I am familiar with the open mapping theorem but that applies to surjective linear maps.

Comment: This follows from the invariance of domain theorem. Do you have access to such tools?

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware of that theorem. I just solved the above question for the case $f: R \to R$ (it was an exercise). So I was curious if it can be solved for $R^n$ case!! It seems it is a big theorem. @William

Comment: You need $O$ to be open. Otherwise, this is false. $[0, 1] \ni  x \mapsto x \in \Bbb R$ is injective and continuous but it is not open. For instance $[0, 1]$ is an open subset of $[0, 1]$ in the subspace topology but its image $[0, 1]$ is not open in $\Bbb R$.

Comment: "for each open subset $A \subseteq O$,   $f(O)$ is open subset of $R^n$" does not make sense. Probably you mean $f(A)$.

Comment: @PaulFrost  right. Sorry didn't state the question properly. But yes I got all things I wanted to know. I don't mind if the question gets closed.

Answer (score 3):

Yes for an open set $O$ in $\Bbb R^n$ into $\Bbb R^n$ an injective continuous function $f$ defined on $O$ is open (in particular $f[O]$ must be open too). This deep theorem (due to Brouwer) is called the invariance of domain theorem (domain being an old fashioned name for open subset of Euclidean space, called "Gebiet" in German). It's quite non-trivial. The simplest proof I know involves dimension theory and the Brouwer fixed point theorem (both areas in which Brouwer was also a pioneer). Most courses nowadays treat it as a consequence of algebraic topology techniques (homology and/or homotopy groups) so it's not very accessible to beginning students. So tell us what the context / background of your course is or we cannot suggest any proof technique. The $\Bbb R$ case is indeed elementary (as is BFPT in that dimension).

Comment: The Borsuk (or the equivalent Borsuk-Ulam) theorem provides a simple proof. These theorems can be proved elementary, though the most easiest proof of them is by degree theory.

Comment: @MartinVäth Borsuk-Ulam can also be proved from dimension theory and BFPT. They're all closely related results, proved first around the same time.

Comment: Indeed, there are several dozens of closely related theorems, and in fact most of them can easily be seen to be equivalent. (However, my feeling is that domain invariance is "strictly weaker" in the sense that Borsuk-Ulam cannot easily be proved from it; I might be wrong, of course.)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I gave it up.  :)  I thought it can be an exercise-level problem. But I  was obviously wrong.  I think the case $ R^n \to R$ is elementary too, as it can be reduced to $R \to R$ case. I tried reducing $R^2 \to  R^2$  to $R \to R$ case but I didn't succeed.

Comment: @Redshoes yeah famous mathematicians tried to prove it in the 1920s too. But Brouwer was the one with the right ideas. It was a long standing problem for a while so easy it’s not.